# How can i search for a character in a string and save a variable with the text after that character?

Tags: php

I have a string with the following content

```
http://www.mysite.com/test.php?http://www.anotherwebsite.com
```

how can i save the second url in a php variable?

i mean, the url after the interrogation mark.

Comment: unusual syntax, i would expect "http://www.mysite.com/test.php?other=http://www.anotherwebsite.com
" if you don't have control overt that check $_GET and $_SERVER to see what you have to work with

Comment: @cillosis, ok and your point is what ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you had the following

```
$double_url = 'http://www.mysite.com/test.php?http://www.anotherwebsite.com';
```

then you could do this

```
$second_url = substr(strstr($double_url, '?http'), 1);
```

OR this

```
$second_url = preg_replace('/.*\?(http.*)/', '$1', $double_url);
```

OR this

```
$second_url = substr($double_url, strpos($double_url, '?http')+1);
```

OR many other approaches that will give you the same result.

I am concerned with using ? as a delimiter between URLs because the ? is a valid and important part of the full URI. For this reason my examples use `'?http'` instead of just `'?'` but there are still potential pitfall situations even with `'?http'`

Answer (score 1):

You're in luck, PHP has functions for that! They are called [strpos()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) and [substr()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) and this is how they work:

```
$haystack = "http://www.mysite.com/test.php?http://www.anotherwebsite.com";
$needle = "?";
$needle_pos = strpos($haystack,$needle);
$text_after_needle = substr($haystack,$needle_pos+1);
```

There are actually MANY ways to do this. It can be accomplished with explode() and grabbing the second array element. It could also be done using regular expressions. The above code is just a simple way to search for a character in a string and grab any text after that.

Comment: why not just explode on the ?

Comment: I wrote below my code that explode() is a possible solution. Each solution has it's own purpose but as the problem is relatively trivial I wanted to provide an answer that is simple and easy to understand.

Answer (score 1):

Where:

`$url = 'http://www.mysite.com/test.php?http://www.anotherwebsite.com';`

Try:

`$url2 = end(explode('?',$url));`

Then:

`echo $url2;`

Will be:

`http://www.anotherwebsite.com`

Answer (score 1):

Try this example.

```
<?php
$url = "http://www.mysite.com/test.php?http://www.anotherwebsite.com";
$params = parse_url($url);
$otherSite = $params['query'];
echo $otherSite;
?>
```